# I am using the cursor() method to execute my query in python but it gives an error

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I want to fetch data from a particular row from the database for which I am using the cursor() method to execute my query in python but it gives an error.
Here is my code:

```
sr = sr_no_var.get()
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', host='localhost', 
                               database='college', password='$@ffron@09')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select QRcode from student where Serial_number=%s",(sr))
starting_index = cur.fetchall()
print(starting_index[0][0])
```

This code gives the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\priyasingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\New Volume\PycharmProjects\trial\student2.py", line 26, in display
    cur.execute("select QRcode from student where Serial_number=%s",(sr))
  File "F:\New Volume\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "F:\New Volume\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 651, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "F:\New Volume\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 538, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

what can I try to remove this error?

Comment: what is the type of `sr` object? you could try converting to `str` explicitly: `cur.execute("select QRcode from student where Serial_number=%s",str(sr))`

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Keep in mind, it should be `(sr,)`.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Type of sr object is an integer

Answer (score 1):

```
cur.execute("select QRcode from student where Serial_number=%s" % sr)
```

When you use % as a placeholder for the parameters in the string, you don't need to (,) after the string But You should use % instead, and then write the values you want.

And when you use a few % in the string, to fill in the values, you have to put the values ​​in parentheses later. It should be noted that it is not required for one.

Comment: `%` is the placeholder for parameter creation in `mysql-connector` for python, not string formatting one.

Comment: yes, you're right. Valid for all strings in Python and works like `.format ()`

Comment: Anyway, this will lead path to sql injection.